# the method "get" isn't defined for class query

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

error: the method "get" isn't defined for  class query

i dont know much about how to use query to get data from firestore and how to show it in the text please advice somthing

```
getData(String docId)async{
  final  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('listofprods').where('id', isEqualTo: docId).get(); // error in the get
  return snapshot;
  }
}
```

also getting error in futurebuilder that method [] was callled on null when i use getdocument() instead of get()

```
FutureBuilder(
                future: fd.getData('ac1'),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  return Container(
                    decoration:
                        BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(snapshot.data['name'].toString()),
                      trailing: Text(snapshot.data['icon'].toString()),
                      onTap: (){
                        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Ac()));
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
         ),
```

Answer (score 2):

To get a single document you shouldn't query the database, you should just get it;)

```
await Firestore.instance.collection('listofprods').doc(docId).get();
```

the futureBuilder sohuld look like that:

```
FutureBuilder(
                future: Firestore.instance.collection('listofprods').doc(docId).get(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
                  return Container(
                    decoration:
                        BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(snapshot.data['name'].toString()),
                      trailing: Text(snapshot.data['icon'].toString()),
                      onTap: (){
                        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Ac()));
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
         ),
```

Btw, you may extact the `Firestore.instance.collection('listofprods').doc(docId).get()` to another function,
but there's no need to make it async, instead return the Future itself (don't add await).

Comment: wait a minute, what do you mean by `.where('id', isEqualTo: docId)`?

Comment: are you trying to get the document 'listofprods/docId'?

Comment: the id is the name of the document yes

Comment: Oh! you're not supposed to do it that way at all... I'll update my answer

Comment: okay bro but i want to use .where query can you tell me about that because i already done this how can i use the .where query in it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205184/discussion-between-noam-and-lalit-rawat).

Answer (score 0):

In the FutureBuilder you have to check for data has come from the database yet or not..You can use `snapshot.hasData`

```
FutureBuilder(
                future: Firestore.instance.collection('listofprods').doc(docId).get(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if(snapshot.hasData)
                   return Container(
                     decoration:
                        BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                     child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(snapshot.data['name'].toString()),
                      trailing: Text(snapshot.data['icon'].toString()),
                      onTap: (){
                        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Ac()));
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                  else
                     return CircularProgressIndicator();
                },
         ),
```

However this procedure is wrong as we should use `DocumentSnapshot` instead of `QuerySnapshot` if we want to fetch a perticualar document.and we should use `StreamBuilder` instead of `FutureBuilder`.